# Add hyperlink to textbox in Access Report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, ms-access-reports

I have an access report that I am populating a textbox on the report from VBA code.  I am in need of a way to add a hyperlink to certain text in the textbox so that it will read like the below, so that only one word in the textbox is a hyperlink

```
This is text in textbox.  We are filled with random facts about fun stuff, 
and great <hyperlink>things</hyperlink>!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the tags `vba` and `access-vba` so I can provide a VBA solution for you. If you add a text box to your report, and set the name to `textbox1` and open the properties and change the `Text Format = Rich Text` then you can use `HTML` in the VBA to code a hyperlink.

Now with that being done open the VBE and in whatever event (button click, page load etc) - add this syntax

```
Dim url as String
url = "http://www.google.com"

Me.textbox1.SetFocus
Me.txtbox1.Text = "Text here for whatever now let's add the hyperlink " & _
                  "<a href = " & url & ">Hyperlink Text</a>!!!."
```

Now when you view the report in `Report View` the site you put in for the variable `url`
will be a hyperlink from the text above `Hyperlink Text`